# Weyl Transformations and Group actions

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, symmetry, group-theory

I have the following question.

Let $(M,g_{ab})$ be a Riemannian manifold $M$ with metric $g$, and with an action of a Lie group $G$. Moreover, the Riemannian metric $g_{ab}$ is taken to be invariant under the action of the Lie group $G$ (i.e. the action is isometric with respect to $g_{ab}$).

Now, I perform the change of metric $g_{ab}(x) \rightarrow g'_{ab}(x) = e^{\phi(x)}g_{ab}(x)$. Is the new metric also invariant under the action of the Lie group $G$ (i.e. is the action of $G$ isometric with respect to $g'_{ab}$)?

Comment: This seems to be a purely mathematical question.

Comment: The answer is positive. However this is a purely mathematical question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll choose the right community next time.

Comment: The question is purely mathematical, but the answer is not positive. Just choose a conformal rescaling of flat space to a metric with non-constant sectional curvature. Such a metric necessarily has less isometries than the flat metric.